# Jquery ui autocomplete not showing, but shows on browser console

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, jquery

What is happening but my auto suggest not showing but when the ajax call happens I see the data in my console **im** using **JSONP** since this is cross domain.any suggestion would be helpful.

html:

```
<form action="search.asp" id="searchform">
            <p class="search">
            <input class="queryAutocomplete"  id="query" type="textbox" name="query" style="margin-left:-180px;width:105% !important;" value=""/>
            <INPUT type="hidden" name="pr" value="test">
            <input type="submit" class="searchbutton" value="Search"/>
            </form>
```

script:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
// add autocomplete
$("#query.queryAutocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {

        $.ajax({
            crossDomain:true, 
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            url: "http://url.com/search/autocomplete.json",
            data: {
                pr: $("input[name='pr']").val(),
                term: request.term
            },
            success: function(data) {
                response(data[1]);
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    open: function(e, ui) {

        var term = $("#query").val();
        var acData = $(this).data("uiAutocomplete");
        acData.menu.element.find("a").each(function() {
            var a = $(this);
            var completion = a.text();
            var pos = completion.indexOf(term);
            var txt = "";
            if(pos != 0) {
                txt += "<span class='ui-autocomplete-completion'>"
                    + completion.substr(0, pos) + "</span>"
            }
            txt += "<span class='ui-autocomplete-term'>" + term + "</span>";
            if(pos + term.length < completion.length) {
                txt += "<span class='ui-autocomplete-completion'>"
                    + completion.substr(pos + term.length) + "</span>";
            }
            a.html(txt);
        });
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $("#query").val(ui.item.value)
            .closest("form").submit();
    },
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to see what's going wrong without a live example (such as on jsfiddle), but looks like you're using the open event to modify the selectable list of options to format it to your requirements.

Instead, you should override the _renderItem function of the autocomplete - try searching for ".data("uiAutocomplete")._renderItem" to get examples.

Comment: i get this on the console log as well. Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type application/x-suggestions+json:

Comment: Have you tried debugging through the code? Run it in firefox, using firebug to set a breakpoint in the event handler code, so you can then step through it. You can also look at the network traffic to see if you are getting correctly formed JSON back from the web service. That's all I can suggest without a live example to look at.

Comment: yeah it doesn't return - it fails but the data returns in the log it's a MIME type application/x-suggestions+json that;s not configured. correctly

Answer (score 0):

May be z-index of autocomplete is less than z-index of div containing textbox. So it is not visible.

You can look for this by searching for classes used by autocomplete plugin in DOM using developer tools.

Comment: not its not that the error in the console log Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type application/x-suggestions+json: